Equipment and technique to climb tree with rope thrown over branch
Let's say I can throw a rope over a sturdy branch. Now, both ends of the rope are on the ground. I'd like to climb up to the branch, using a climbing harness and an ascender, figure 8 metal belay, or similar. I want to use a prussik to put my foot in below the harness, so I can "walk" up. When I'm at the top, I want to rappel down. How can I do it safely with the least amount of material? Please provide very specific instructions. Links and pictures are appreciated too! Thank you :-)

Least amount of material? Two prusik cords (I'd use 3 m and 5 m), harness, one long sling, two carabiners.
You prusik up with the two cords -- one to your harness, one for the foot. I prefer to do this not on the double rope, but instead make a figure-eight-loop on one end of the rope, and clip that end to the other strand with the carabiner, then tighten the loop around the branch.  Otherwise, you need very good prusiks or better knots over the two strands (but can get rid of one carabiner). But only do it if you are sure you can reach the top :)
When you are at the top, you self-belay with the sling and one carabiner around the branch. Undo the carabiner loop in the rope, pull it around the branch until the middle.  Then use one carabiner and one cord with an HMS-based abseiling technique like this, where you don't need a plate or other device.
Now, this is the bare minimum. Several remarks or improvements:

Use a static rope for this, if you can get one.
If you feel safe enough on the branch, you can of course just climb around there and get rid of the loop. This does have advantages later (see last point).
On the other hand, if you believe you could fall -- don't use a loop. It's made from static material. If you fall into a loop with some slack, it transfers the whole energy onto you and might hurt you, or could potentially break.  In such a case (e.g., when you plan to work above the branch), prefer a via ferrata set or a personal anchor system with a dynamic rope.
One of the simplest improvements I'd strongly recommend is to use a normal plate device for abseiling, instead of some unfamiliar HMS variant with a single carabiner. That's the first step away from minimalism I'd recommend.
TiBlocks are much more convenient than knots for the prusiking. Or even special ascender devices, if you have access to them.
The hardest part of all this is taking away the load from the self-belay loop when you want to start abseiling (as you want to transfer the load to the HMS or plate and remove the loop). It requires strength and awkward movements.  You can use a cord around the branch to stand in and take the load from the belay system, but make sure you can reach that far once you hang freely.

And be careful handing around there. Suspension trauma is real, I have seen it.

Second that the hardest part is transitioning from rope climbing to abseil. Practise that skill close to ground first.
Also don't trust your life to the prusiks. Make some sort of tie offs as you ascend. (A loop on the ropes clipped to a carabiner on your belay loop or similar)

To make the switch over easier from ascent to descent, what about using a figure 8 tied with an auto stop for both, as shown in the last example here? https://www.ropelab.com.au/figure-8-descenders/

I personally do trust my live to the prusics; that is exactly what is tought in state of the art mountaineering self-rescue techniques. However, I agree insofar as this is not an emergency situation, but a planned move, and therefore some redundancy isn't a bad idea. The tie-off idea sounds inefficient and potentially dangerous to me, though (you fall into potentially long slack). I'd recommend professional ascender devices over it.

And figure 8s I trust even less :D they are practically declared as outdated where I come from. (The technique is cool though).
